# Initializing NSArray *_strong with an expression of incompatible type void

Tags: ios, objective-c, nssortdescriptor

I referred [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SortDescriptors/Articles/Creating.html) link as I am trying to sort the data from web service in table View. My first question is can we sort data in a mutable array? I get this compiler error in the following code.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Name" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortArrayWithObject = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedArray = [tempArray sortUsingDescriptors:sortArrayWithObject]; // error
```

`tempArray` is `NSMutableArray` and not `NSArray`.

Comment: try that NSArray *sortedArray = [[NSArray arrayWithArray:tempArray] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortArrayWithObject];

Comment: my silly misktake.. thanks Greg

Comment: Understand that `void`, like most keywords in C, is way overloaded.  `void` by itself means nothing at all (literally) vs `void*` which means a pointer with no type info.  You were trying to assign nothing at all to your target pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue was because of a silly mistake. I modified API call as below and it now works.

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [tempArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortArrayWithObject];
```

Comment: Surely you mean `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors` not `sortArrayUsingDescriptors`

Answer (score 1):

The method `sortUsingDescriptors:` returns `void`, that is why you get this message. The `NSMutableArray` to which the message is sent (in your case, `tempArray`) is directly modified by the `sortUsingDescriptors:` method.

Answer (score 1):

It returns `void`, you are expecting `NSArray` from it.

```
- (void)sortUsingDescriptors:(NSArray *)sortDescriptors
```

Your code should be :

```
[tempArray sortUsingDescriptors:sortArrayWithObject];
```

Above will ***sort the receiving array (tempArray) using a given array of sort descriptors.***